# Exiting Recursive function searching subdirectories

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

I'm trying to get a list of all subdirectories in a given directory recursively, because the existing command apparently isn't good enough.
I can successfully get the directories, but can't seem to leave the recursive algorithm. I'm sure there's bound to be an easy way of doing it that I'm not seeing. Any help would be great!

```
public static public void directorySearch(ref List<DirectoryInfo> subs, ref DirectoryInfo dir, ref List<FileInfo> fileEntries, ref int k)
{
  do
    {
      foreach (DirectoryInfo elements in dir.GetDirectories())
      {
        subs.Add(elements);
      }
      k++;
      DirectoryInfo fi = subs[k];
      directorySearch(ref subs, ref fi, ref fileEntries, ref k);
    } while (??????);
      //This will be used once function is working to get files in all directories
        /*
      foreach (FileInfo f in dir.GetFiles()
      {
          fileEntries.Add(f);
      }*/
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing the parameters in by `ref`? Only `k` seems to need it.

Comment: Subs does too, unless I create it in the function.  And same will go for fileEntries

Comment: No, `subs` and `fileEntries` do not need `ref`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try this to get the directories:

```
public static IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> DirectorySearch(DirectoryInfo dir)
{
    return
        dir
            .GetDirectories()
            .SelectMany(x => DirectorySearch(x))
            .StartWith(dir);
}
```

Then you can do `DirectorySearch("C:\My\Path").SelectMany(x => x.GetFiles())` to get the files.

---

Alternatively you can use this:

```
public static IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> DirectorySearch(DirectoryInfo dir)
{
    yield return dir;
    foreach (DirectoryInfo x in dir.GetDirectories())
        foreach (DirectoryInfo y in DirectorySearch(x))
            yield return y;
}
```

---

Or even this:

```
public static List<DirectoryInfo> DirectorySearch(DirectoryInfo dir)
{
    List<DirectoryInfo> subs = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
    subs.Add(dir);
    foreach (DirectoryInfo x in dir.GetDirectories())
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo y in DirectorySearch(x))
        {
            subs.Add(y);
        }
    }
    return subs;
}
```

Comment: @Hooch - All three are identical in their function.

Answer (score 3):

You dont need a loop for this. Use the built in classes in `using System.Collections.Generic`

This will search recursively:

```
    public static IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> GetSubdirectories(string path)
    {
        return new DirectoryInfo(path).EnumerateDirectories("*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    }
```

Comment: So we specifically can't use the AllDirectories option

Answer (score -1):

You need to check if the directory you are currently handling actually has sub-directories. If it does, you do `subs.Add(elements)` if it doesn't, you `return`. Thats what causes the function to stop once it reaches the end.

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo elements in dir.GetDirectories())
{
  subs.Add(elements);
}

k++;
DirectoryInfo fi = subs[k];

if (fi[k].GetDirectories().length > 0)
{
  directorySearch(ref subs, ref fi, ref fileEntries, ref k);
} else {
  return;
}
```

I just wrote this off the top of my head so you will have to debug this but it will give you an idea of how to handle this I hope.